# Battery at 0,0 Wh and not charging, even though "present: yes"

Tags: laptop, battery

My Asus x55u cannot use its battery. Power statistics say the battery is at 0% and charging, 0 seconds till full/empty, and when the power cable is unplugged it immediately dies. (No shutdown)

However, Ubuntu does recognize the battery (the power indicator is red, the info says `present: yes`) if the battery is connected.

This leads me to believe it's not just a hardware problem.

Also, Ubuntu acts unexpectedly. I had this problem on Ubuntu 12.04, before upgrading to 14.04. On 12.04, the menu bar indicated `(not present)`. After upgrading to 14.04 the problem persisted but the indicator light was flashing. I tried lots of changes to the `/etc/default/grub` file, and restarted the computer in different ways, and now the indicator light is again constantly red. The menu bar now shows only the icon of a charging battery.

I find the info and state of my battery especially weird:

```
$ cat /proc/acpi/battery/BAT0/info 
present:                 yes
design capacity:         49500 mWh
last full capacity:      10021 mWh
battery technology:      rechargeable
design voltage:          10800 mV
design capacity warning: 4950 mWh
design capacity low:     495 mWh
cycle count:             0
capacity granularity 1:  495 mWh
capacity granularity 2:  495 mWh
model number:            K55--44
serial number:
battery tipe:            LIon
OEM info:                ASUSTek
```

```
$ cat /proc/acpi/battery/BAT0/state
present:                 yes
capacity state:          critical
charging state:          charging
present rate:            0 mW
remaining capacity:      0 mWh
present voltage:         7618 mV
```

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried a battery check via the Bios to verify it really is no hardware problem? It sure sounds like one.

Comment: To second what Bruni said, everything I see, especially in bat info and state, leads me to believe the battery is bad.